# Hide element based on attribute value jquery

Tags: jquery, attributes, hide

How can I hide child div based on the `attribute` value of parent div. I have following **markup**:

```
<div class="offerContainer">
    <div class="Offers" producttype="CIP">
        <div class="buttons_wrap"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="Offers" producttype="P">
        <div class="buttons_wrap"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="Offers" producttype="CIP">
        <div class="buttons_wrap"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And I want to hide `buttons_wrap` only when  atrribute value of `producttype` is "CIP".

Something like:

```
if($(obj).parents(".offersContainer").find('.Offers').attr('producttype').value == "CIP")
    $('.buttons_wrap').hide();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$('.buttons_wrap').each(function(){
    if($(this).parents('.Offers').attr('producttype') == "CIP"){
        $(this).hide();
    }
});
```

JSFIDDLE Example:

https://jsfiddle.net/Panomosh/kL11m73L/

Comment: Yes, Simple and Works!

Comment: Normally, keeping it simple is the best approach! No problem @HumaAli

Answer (score 0):

### Try This custom method

```js
$(function() {
var $offers = $('.Offers');
$offers.each(function() {
var productType = $(this).attr('producttype');
if(productType != "CIP")
{ 
   $(this).children().hide();
}
});
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="offerContainer">
    <div class="Offers" producttype="CIP">
        <div class="buttons_wrap"><button>First</button></div>
    </div>
    <div class="Offers" producttype="P">
        <div class="buttons_wrap"><button>Second</button></div>
    </div>
    <div class="Offers" producttype="CIP">
        <div class="buttons_wrap"><button>Third</button></div>
    </div>
</div>
```